# Triangle within a triangle CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create the following setup for a navigation structure.

[image]

I'm able to get the white down triangle working without an issue but how do I place yet another triangle (green lines) over the top of the first one without a full border/background or using an image?  I can only get a solid green arrow over the white one and that's not what I want to do.

This is what I currently have.

```css
 .custom-nav li a:after { 
    content: ""; 
    z-index: 99; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 40px 150px 0 150px; 
    border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 173%; left: -75px; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="custom-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Environment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Health</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "without a full border/background"?

Comment: I just need the green lines, not the filled in triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option to get something like that is to use an SVG:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #DEE;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 0 50px;
  background: content-box white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button__text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button__triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform ease-in 150ms;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button:hover > .button__triangle {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.button__triangle--big {
  fill: white;
}

.button__triangle--small {
  fill: white;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-in 150ms;
}

.button:hover .button__triangle--small {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button__text">OPTION 1</span>
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 50" class="button__triangle">
      <polygon points="0,0 100,50 200,0" class="button__triangle--big" />
      <polyline points="50,5 100,30 150,5" class="button__triangle--small" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  
  <button class="button">
    <span class="button__text">OPTION 2</span>
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 50" class="button__triangle">
      <polygon points="0,0 100,50 200,0" class="button__triangle--big" />
      <polyline points="50,5 100,30 150,5" class="button__triangle--small" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why SVG over straight CSS? Responsiveness or some other reason?

Comment: It offers more freedom to generate more complex shapes and gives you additional control with properties like `stroke-linecap`. You could use CSS borders or gradients to create something similar, but you would not be able to adjust that, for example. Also, at least in Chrome, SVGs look smoother than CSS gradients.

Comment: Also, it's easier to play around with what you are designing as each shape is an element. Don't need the white triangle? Remove its `polygon`. With CSS you usually end up using a combination of HTML elements and CSS pseudoelements and properties to render a single shape, so it's might become harder to adjust it later. For example, take a look at https://diana-adrianne.com/purecss-francine/.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.  BTW, that link is crazy!

Comment: We tried both approaches and found the SVG to be a better look. Worked well once we became familiar with how to draw it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Multiple background can do this:

```css
.box {
  --w:160px; /* width of the arrow */
  --h:40px;  /* height of the arrow*/
  --b:2px;   /* thickness of the green arrow */
  --o:20%;   /* offset of the green arrow */
  
  /* gadient coloration, white then the green border then white again then transparent */
  --g:#fff var(--o),
      green var(--o) calc(var(--o) + var(--b)),
      #fff calc(var(--o) + var(--b) + 1px) 49.8%,
      transparent 50%;

  height:50px;
  margin:5px;
  border-bottom:var(--h) solid transparent; /* the arrow will take the border space */
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,var(--g)) calc(50% + calc(var(--w)/4)) 100% border-box,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,var(--g)) calc(50% - calc(var(--w)/4)) 100% border-box,
    #fff padding-box;
  background-size:calc(var(--w)/2) var(--h);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


body {
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--w:200px;--h:60px;--o:30%;--b:5px"></div>

<div class="box" style="--w:180px;--h:30px;--o:10%;--b:3px"></div>
```